# Docker is uninstalled still v box not working

Tags: linux

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu.

> Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS (Last=0xc000000d/87) (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).

```
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSao7.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening due to a conflict between Hyper-V (which uninstalling docker does not deactivate) and Virtualbox. Check to see if Hyper-V is enabled. To do this (assuming you're running docker on windows)

1. go to control panel's "turn Windows features on or off" options
2. search for Hyper-V. If it's checked, Hyper-V is still enabled, and is likely the cause of the issue. uncheck it, and restart your computer.
3. try to launch virtualbox again.